# How to expand multiple properties on OData

Tags: odata

Consider I have this OData expression:

```
http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Categories?
    $expand=Products/Category
```

It will correctly expand the `Products.Category`.

Now I want to expand another property too. For example 'Products.Supplier`.

I've tried duplicating the `$expand` usage:

```
http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Categories?
    $expand=Products/Category
    &$expand=Products/Supplier
```

but it failed returning this error:

```
Query parameter '$expand' is specified, but it should be specified exactly once.
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to OData ABNF, expand syntax should be:

> expand = '$expand' EQ expandItem *( COMMA expandItem )

Which amounts to:

```
$expand=expandItem1,expandItem2,expandItem3,...
```

So please try:

http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Categories?$expand=Products/Category,Products/Supplier

---

For more information, see:

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#ExpandSystemQueryOption

Answer (score 33):

You can also try this syntax for expanding multiple levels:

```
$expand=Products($expand=Category),...
```

This works well with MS OData implementation in WebAPI.

Comment: Upvoted because this page is top of the google results for expanding multiple levels of OData even though that's not the OP's question and this answer solved my related problem.

Answer (score 5):

For our SAP consultants out there:
We're able to use multi-levels in oData as well.
You need to pass it this way:

```
<host>/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/Identification?$expand=to_Parent,to_Parent/to_Role
```

The example above provides you the ability to fetch the expands of another expand. In this case to_parent -> to_Role. "to_Role" is only available at the parent level.