# How have more than two expands in restier asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, odata, restier

I have a RESTier service and I need to use more than two expand in browser Url like below:

```
http://localhost:64747/api/SI24/Customers?$filter=Id%20eq%2067922&$expand=Bns($expand=Parvandes($expand=ParvandeStateLogs))
```

I must not make any controller for this service. If you see in my url you can understand that I must navigate between four tables. The tables are Customers , Bns , Parvandes , ParvandeStateLogs. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is expand?

Comment: expand works like join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand multiple properties on OData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977434/how-to-expand-multiple-properties-on-odata)

Comment: No, this address do not work for me. If you see in my url you can understand that I must navigate between four tables. The tables are Customers , Bns , Parvandes , ParvandeStateLogs and the method in your address don't work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself against my will decided to make one controller for this query and added the attribute of "[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 50)]" over its action as below:

```
public class CustomersController : ODataController
{
    private SI24 db = new SI24();

    // GET: api/Customers
    [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 50)]
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return db.Customers;
    }
}
```